# Change Between two Stateful Widgets while staying in the Same Location using a ToggleButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, state-management

I have a ToggleButtons Widget in my application and I want to switch between two different StatefulWidget classes (both of which are fairly complicated) when a user clicks on the toggle. I have tried using an animatedCrossFade however I was not able to switch between the two screens.

```
AnimatedCrossFade(
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
              firstChild: AppointmentMain(),
              secondChild: RequestPage(),
              crossFadeState:
                  _first ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
            )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) to switch between two different Widget.

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      child: _first? AppointmentMain() : RequestPage(),
    )
```

Comment: If this worked for you then please upvote my answer. It will be really helpful to me as well as others.

Answer (score 0):

Have One Main Widget that uses a button to load the separate widgets.

```
void main() {
   runApp(MaterialApp(
 home: myApp(),
 ));

class myApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myAppState createState() => _myApp();
}

class _myAppState extends State<Home> {

 int counter = 1;

  return Scaffold(
   body: RaisedButton(
     on pressed loadFirstWidget
   ),
 );
}

Widget loadWidget() {
 setState() {
  counter += 1;
 }

 if (counter % 2 == 0) {
    return firstWidget();
  }
  return secondWidget();
}
```

Hopefully this helps!